# What is the difference between request and http modules in node.js?

Tags: javascript

My task is a very simple one, send an http/https request to a server, get back the HTML,JSON or XML and process the data.

I understand that there are 2 modules that can do the module part. 
nodejs.org/api/http.html
and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

I guess request is more advanced. Other than that is there any difference between the 2 which makes one more suitable or less suitable for the task I said?

Comment: This is a very vague question. One is a basic standard package. The other one add some sugar and uses the first one.

Comment: `http` and `https` are built-in modules, they are integrated to the official Node.js API compared to `request` which is a third-party package that uses the built-in modules (it could be easier to use `request` but it adds a dependency that you may not need like jQuery does for JavaScript).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `http` package contains support for the raw HTTP protocol. While it can do everything, often it's a bit clumsy to use.

The `request` module uses the `http` module and adds a lot of sugar to make it easier to digest: A lot of common cases can be handled with just a tiny bit of code, it supports piping request data, forwarding requests to a different server, etc.